# Shoulder shrug with weight limitation

Tags: exercise, shoulders, dumbbells

I am doing shoulder shrugs, I can do 66 pounds, but that is max weight available.
My question is can i use barbell like dumbbells and do side shrugs or does weight being far away from center will affect exercise. In barbell weights are far away from center hence more torque while with dumb bell less torque so would not it be hard to do shrugs with barbell

Comment: Can you explain your concern a little more clearly?

Comment: @rrirower edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most folks doing heavy shrugs use barbells; dumbbells simply don't have enough weight. [It's in EXRX's index](http://www.exrx.net/WeightExercises/TrapeziusUpper/BBShrug.html). EXRX also has [a great list of common errors during the shrug](http://www.exrx.net/Kinesiology/Errors.html#ShoulderShrugs) you may want to read about, particularly the "rolling" motion that people tend to do.

Not that you asked, but personally I don't find much use for them. If you're deadlifting, rowing, doing barbell presses, and cleans (a typical compound week) you'll be beating the tar out of your shoulders and upper back anyway.